# Java Future, call cancel method twice

Tags: java, sleep, interrupt

I have a running task they do some steps, I can start `future = executor.submit(callable)` and stop `future.cancel()` it with start and stop Buttons. Between each step the Task looks if he cancelled then return else run further.

In a step he sleeps for example 2 sec. When cancel the task in this two seconds the sleep will interrupted and the task will run further to the end of the step. But if I start the task between the interruption and the end of the step they should run further with the next step (Don't create a new Callable run further with which one is running). That all works fine.

But when I will cancel the Task a second time with `future.cancel()` then it does not react.
How can I cancel a callable twice or "un cancel" it to cancel again.
The call of `cancel()` is not for cancel the Task, only for interrupt the sleep.

Here is a little code example that will help you understand my problem:

```
public void start() {
    if(currentAlarm != null){ //already running
      changeTransmitterStatus(AlarmTransmitterStatus.TRANSMIT_ALARM);
      return;
    }
    changeTransmitterStatus(AlarmTransmitterStatus.RUNNING);
    //transmitter is the callable and result the future
    result = executorPool.submit(transmitter);
  }

  public void stop() {
    changeTransmitterStatus(AlarmTransmitterStatus.STOP);
    result.cancel(true); //call this twice it doesn't react
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its pretty hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but in short you cannot "un-cancel" a cancelled task in Java's executor service, once you cancel the task then it will be removed from the queue so you cannot "un-cancel".

Comment: Ok thanks, I try to ask another easier to understand way to solve my problem. Can I interrupt a sleep in a Task without cancel the Task? So only interrupt the `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: With Java's executor service I am not sure if you can do that directly, but you can always use Java's vanilla interrupt mechanism to achieve it.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I can't find much when I search after "Java vanilla interrupt mechanism" and I don't understand what you mean with it.

Comment: I did it, thank you!